# mod_rewrite /$variable/file.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying to attempt this, but I am unable to yield any results. I'm trying to rewrite a variable into a "directory" in the url to multiple files.. I better explain this is what I mean.

Without the rewrite:

```
/index.php?var=test

/admin/panel.php?var=test

/faq.php?var=test

/directory/test.php?var=test
```

With the rewrite:

```
/test/index.php

/test/admin/panel.php

/test/faq.php

/test/directory/test.php
```

I'd like to be able to pass other variables to the files as well.. example:

```
/test/index.php?user=1&session=1233445
```

I realize that I could do a rewrite rule for every physical file and directory.. but I want it to be dynamic so if I add files to my site I don't have to keep editing the .htaccess file. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*?/?)(index|panel|faq|test)\.php$ /$2$3.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Jon it works for only files in the main directory. I'm looking for it to also working dynamically for real directories as well..

`/test/directory/file.php`

And I did not specify that I'd like the variable to be passed to any type of file as well. Thank you!

Comment: Jon, we are getting closer but I'm not reaching the result I am looking for. I'd just like to pass "var" to all REAL files in all directories that are real. The code you've provided keeps rewriting to the main directory. I need "var" to be passed to all files no matter what their name is and no matter what the extension is... Again thanks for the reply. I'm sorry if my explanation is a little confusing..